# JSON text did not start with array error in JSONSerialization Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4

I am getting the following error when performing the request below.

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start
>   with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or
>   object and option to allow fragments not set.}

```
@IBAction func onPostTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        let parameters = ["Name": "Yogesh", "Mobile": "1212121212", "DOB": "1122/12/12", "Address": "qwqwqwqw"]
        //https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/webservice/Register.php") else { return }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else { return }
        request.httpBody = httpBody

        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let response = response {
                print(response)
            }

            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                    print(json)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }

        }.resume()

    }
```

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: I guess the error is the `catch` of `JSONSerialization.jsonObject()`? Mind showing us `let dataStr = String(data: data, encoding:.utf8)` (and print it)? But I guess that `dataStr` is not JSON Valid (there are online JSON Validator, check it).

Comment: > 200 SO search results for *"JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set"*, and none of them helped??

Comment: I tried that solution but i am new so can't understand that solution @martin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error explains the issue, the JSON received doesn't start with an object or an array and Allow Fragments is not set.

Check your JSON is what you would expect to receive

You can enable allow fragments like so..

```
try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
```

Allow fragments allows you to load partial JSON data that does not map directly to an array or Dictionary

From the docs:

> Specifies that the parser should allow top-level objects that are not
>   an instance of NSArray or NSDictionary.